# SQL Multiple-Row Subqueries Comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return department id-s, where the department's min salary is higher than the other department's max salary.
Here's my query:

```
select *
from hr.employees
where (select min(salary) from hr.employees group by department_id) < any (select max(salary) from hr.employees group by department_id)
```

> error I get is: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

even though I use any operator...

Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem is the first subquery, not the second. You are selecting min salary from every department, so that subquery returns as many rows as there are distinct departments. Rather, that should be a correlated subquery. But you also have a mathematical mistake: if you want the min(salary) to be **higher than** something else, then the inequality operator should be `>`, not `<`. But also, you say you want to return department id's, but your query returns employees, not department id's.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. First aggregate salaries grouped by department, collecting the min and the max salary in each department. Then self-join the result (join the result to itself) on the condition in your problem. I use a `with` clause, which allows Oracle to do the aggregation just once. I include the min salary from the "high salaries" department and the max salary from the "low salaries" department just to confirm that the query works as expected. The output is pretty big (27 rows), but not so big that it won't fit in this answer.

```
with d as (
  select department_id, min(salary) as min_sal, max(salary) as max_sal
  from   hr.employees
  group  by department_id
)
select d1.department_id as dept_highsal, d1.min_sal as dept_higsal_min_sal,
       d2.department_id as dept_lowsal , d2.max_sal as dept_lowsal_max_sal
from   d d1 inner join d d2 on d1.min_sal > d2.max_sal
;
```

Output:

```
DEPT_HIGHSAL DEPT_HIGSAL_MIN_SAL DEPT_LOWSAL DEPT_LOWSAL_MAX_SAL
------------ ------------------- ----------- -------------------
          90               17000          80               14000
          90               17000          20               13000
          90               17000         100               12008
          90               17000         110               12008
          90               17000          30               11000
          90               17000          70               10000
          90               17000          60                9000
          90               17000          50                8200
          90               17000                            7000
          90               17000          40                6500
          90               17000          10                4400
          70               10000          60                9000
          70               10000          50                8200
          70               10000                            7000
          70               10000          40                6500
          70               10000          10                4400
         110                8300          50                8200
         110                8300                            7000
         110                8300          40                6500
         110                8300          10                4400
                            7000          40                6500
                            7000          10                4400
         100                6900          40                6500
         100                6900          10                4400
          40                6500          10                4400
          80                6100          10                4400
          20                6000          10                4400
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select d_id1, d_id2
(select department_id d_id1, min(salary) min_salary
 from hr.employees
group by department_id) q1
join 
(select department_id d_id2, max(salary) max_salary
 from hr.employees
 group by department_id) q2
 on q1.min_salary > q2.max_salary
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.

This was a solution:

select * from (select  main_temp.department_id,
min(salary) min_salary ,
(select max(salary) from hr.employees temp where temp.department_id <> main_temp.department_id) others_max
from hr.employees main_temp where department_id is not null group by department_id) where min_salary >  others_max